# Doctrine Cascade Delete OneToMany self Referencing

Tags: php, symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hello i have an issue with my symfony project

I have a listener entity

```
/**
 * Listener
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ListenerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table("listeners", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="sponsor_code", columns={"sponsor_code"})})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Listener implements ListenerInterface
{
    ...
}
```

in this class there is a sponsoredListeners property

```
/**
  * @Groups({"listener_sponsored"})
  *
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Listener", mappedBy="sponsor")
  */
    private $sponsoredListeners;
```

this property is an [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) of Listener entities (the current class)

listeners are added in this array collection using this method

```
/**
  * Add sponsored Listener
  *
  * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Listener $sponsoredListener
  *
  * @return Listener
  */
  public function addSponsoredListener(\AppBundle\Entity\Listener $sponsoredListener)
    {
        if (!$this->sponsoredListeners->contains($sponsoredListener)) {
            $this->sponsoredListeners[] = $sponsoredListener;
        }

        $sponsoredListener->setSponsor($this); // just set the sponsor property for the listener given in parameters of this function (addSponsoredListener)    
        return $this;
    }
```

There problem is that when i try to delete all listeners from my listener tables during my testing i get these errors

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myradio_test`.`listeners`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CEFB12DB12F7FB51` FOREIGN KEY (`sponsor_id`) REFERENCES `listeners` (`id`))

/var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:60
/var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:128
/var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:996
/var/www/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Purger/ORMPurger.php:149
/var/www/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Executor/AbstractExecutor.php:136
/var/www/vendor/liip/functional-test-bundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:451
/var/www/src/ApiBundle/Tests/Controller/ArtistsControllerTest.php:16
/var/www/src/ApiBundle/Tests/Controller/ArtistsControllerTest.php:27
```

if i understand what is happening he is trying to delete listeners with are "linked" with other listeners for sponsoredListeners.

I think i need a cascade delete but not sure how to do it. If someone can explain me it could be really cool

here is the listener table

Column  Type    Comment
id  int(11) Auto Increment
account_id  int(11) NULL
sponsor_id  int(11) NULL
station_id  int(11) NULL
firstname   varchar(100) NULL
gender  varchar(255) NULL
birthyear   int(11) NULL
picture varchar(255) NULL
sponsor_code    varchar(6)
sponsored_at    datetime NULL
created_at  datetime
updated_at  datetime NULL

Comment: if you need more details just tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a class property you need to delete set annotation onDelete="SET NULL" and make it nullable